# Create List by type variable

Tags: java, generics, types

I want to create a List with the specified generic type. The best way to write the problem down is this:

```
public List createListByType(Type myType) {
     return new ArrayList<myType>();
}
```

Since the code above does not work I need a workaround.

[This question has been asked 10 years ago but it is outdated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) Does not work in Java 8.

Comment: In this code, you don't need it. Simply do `return new ArrayList();`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Actually You're right. If I know the type I don't need to define it because I'll put those type of variables.

Comment: @CoralWombat I think Seelenvirtuose was referring to the fact that your method returns a List as a raw type without any Generic parameter. Of course I highly doubt that is what you actually want returned.

Comment: Really, creating a list this way is not needed. You could also call `= new ArrayList<>()` instead of `= createListByType(...)`. So I assume a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You're absolutely right. The way I wanted to do it was just not the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your just creating a new `List` your not needing it. But if you want to add that element to the list or just have the empty list by Type for some reason here's some examples:

```
    public static <T> List<T> createMutableListByType(final Class<T> tClass){
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public static <T> List<T> createImmutableListWithType(final T type){
        return List.of(type);
    }

    public static <T> List<T> createMutableListWithType(final T type){
        final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(type);
        return result;
    }
```